# How to fill DropDownList from Database When Selecting item from previous DropDownList in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I created one DropDownList that contains items like class name(10th,11th,12th and so on) from database. But when I clicked on that class name the second DropDownList can not be loaded with values related to class name from database. So How do I get the values in second DropDownList in PHP.

Comment: See, Frankly Speaking, We Can't Guess Your Code. Show Your Code To Seek Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?--This is 1st dropdown with values that I fetch from database -->

<?php
    $query = "select * from  batch_data where subscriber_reg_code = 
    '".$_SESSION['subCode']."' and 
    branch_reg_code='".$_SESSION['branchCode']."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);                                              
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);     
?>
    <select class="span8" name="sel_class" id="sel_class" 
    onChange="getHouseModel">
   <option value="">Select Class</option>
    <?php 
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $cls_name = $rows['class_name'];             
    ?>    
    <option value="<?php echo $cls_name; ?>"><?php echo $cls_name; ?>
</option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

<?-- And I am trying to fetch data from database on selection of previous 
 Dropdown option  -->
<?php
    $query = "select * from  batch_data where subscriber_reg_code = 
    '".$_SESSION['subCode']."' and class_name='".$cls_name."' and 
    branch_reg_code='".$_SESSION['branchCode']."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    ?>
    <select class="span8" name="sel_batch" id="sel_batch">
    <option value="">Select Batch</option>
    <?php                                             
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $btc_name = $rows['batch_name'];             
    ?>    
     <option value="<?php echo $btc_name; ?>"><?php echo $btc_name; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>

  </select>
```